# How to set img attributes with JS

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to set attributes (width and height) of my all images on page.
So i do something like that:

```html
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

const setImagesAttributes = () => {
    images.forEach(img => {
        img.setAttribute('width', img.clientWidth);
        img.setAttribute('height', img.clientHeight);
    })
}

window.onload = () => {
    setImagesAttributes();
    window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(setImagesAttributes));
}
```

And now something weird happen. So I think 90% of images work correct, the behave in same way like before adding script. But some images have very low height, idk what happend. Why one image behave normally, others not.

Before adding script:
[image]

After script:
[image]

But as i sad over 90% of images works correct. After adding script they have W & H attributes and work fine

Comment: What does it mean when an image doesn't "behave normally"? Or is your script setting the low height to some images?

Comment: What is th underlying reason you want to run this script? Why not use CSS and media queries?